# Proving $(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})$ Is Not A Field

Tags: ring-theory, complex-numbers

Let's $(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})$ be a ordered paired of elements form $\mathbb{C}$ when $\mathbb{C}$ is defined as (a,b).

addition and multiplication is defined as in $\mathbb{C}$.

How do I prove it is not a field if $\mathbb{C}$ is a field

Comment: $(a,b)$ denotes **AN** ordered pair. The set of ordered pairs is usually denoted by $A\times B$. In this case $\Bbb{C\times C}$ is not a field, rather than just $(\Bbb{C,C})$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$(2,0)*(0,2)=(0,0)$. Therefore it has zero-divisors. (2,0) does not have an inverse element. ...